# How to view saved passwords on Chrome iOS?

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ipad

On my desktop I have an extension which prevents websites from reqesting the browser not to recognize the password fields (I imagine they view this feature as unsecure). Now I have synced my passwords with Chrome in iOS, and the extension is not available on iPad. This means that while the 
password has synced, it does not automatically get entered into the password field. So I thought I would just view the saved password and enter it manually. Unfortunately I am unable to do so. If anyone knows how to either view my passwords or otherwise recover it, I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 3):

You can't review your stored Passwords in the Chrome App at all.

On the App and in the Support Documents Apple mentions  to use the url passwords.google.com see [image: Screenshot from Chrome App]

On that Page when you open it on your Moblie it says that you can access your Passwords From all your Divices but not fron this Site see [image: Screenshot from Website]

So i think there is currently no way you can have a Look at your saved Passwords at the Moment.

If you realy need it you should Fill a Bug request and send it to Google so they maybe will fix it in the App.

Comment: This is exactly the pictures I was going to post in a question because what they've written sounds extremely stupid. Well, we're still here, two years later. Google is still doing its thing.

Answer (score 2):

As of June 2019 on iOS 12 on an **iPad Air 2** (app version 74.0.3729.155) I found the following method to work. I do not own an iPhone, so I can’t comment on whether the same works there.

1. Click the menu icon (three dots), then  „Settings“. [image]
2. Enter the passwords submenu.[image]
3. After a short delay, a list of your accounts should be displayed. A search-bar should be located at the top of the dialog. [image]
4. For each entry you can view and copy the password, which will prompt for further authentication (TouchID in my case). [image]

Honestly though, I find that protection too weak. Convenient or not, an account list should never be displayed without explicit authentication. Google seems to still believe that being logged into a device is sufficient authentication, and that nobody ever allows anyone else to access their devices. At least requiring the finger print for accessing the password is an improvement though.

If passwords.google.com works for you, you should urgently make sure that passphrase based end-to-end encryption is enabled on your devices with Chrome. Otherwise you may be syncing sensitive data in a form that is accessible on the server side; While using Chrome in itself already puts significant trust into Google as a company, server-accessible synchronization opens up your data to rogue employees or future server breaches.

As far as I know, Chrome now by default encrypts passwords with your Google password though, so the website should actually be non-functional for everyone, unless they have implemented client-side decryption in the interface and explicitly prompt for the password. But that would be equally possible with the passphrase, so it probably does not apply.

Answer (score 1):

1. Launch your Google Chrome browser.
2. Open the menu with the 'three-dot' button on the far right of the Chrome toolbar.
3. Click "Settings".
4. Scroll down to the bottom and select the "Advanced" option at the bottom of the drop-down menu.
5. Navigate to the "Passwords and forms" feature and click "Manage passwords".
6. Find the website that you wish to show the password by clicking the "eye" icon or you may click the three-dot button to get details about the saved password or remove it.

Also, from the "Manage passwords" feature, you can select any account/website that you wish to edit, remove, or update a password for accessing the specific site again.

Answer (score 0):

You can now actually view (!) passwords on `passwords.google.com` on iOS, by tapping the eye icon next to them.

A word of warning though, in the typical Google fashion they've made a half-assed implementation, complete with the trademark defective and poorly thought through UI. Don't expect to be able to select your entire password if it's longer than, say, 12 characters and happens to contain some sort of punctuation. Copying the password will of course also be out of the question in those cases.

Oh and rotating the device can't be used as a workaround. Also there's no search. Or feedback button.

Thanks Google.

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome for iOS:

1. Go to Settings
2. Tap Save Passwords
3. There should be a list of all passwords you saved. You can delete then using the edit button or swiping left on the password you want to delete

Comment: This does not explain how to view saved passwords.

Comment: @MistaJ - just click on password field and you should see 'show' button

Comment: @MarekBettman There is no Show button on Chrome for iPhone. Chrome for Windows has one, but on the iPhone, there is no button.

Answer (score -1):

View and manage passwords at passwords.google.com

From there sign in to your google account and you will be able to look at all the passwords you have saved. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

You can see them also on passwords.google.com.